# Android - How do i hide the app icon on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have already implemented the right menu (with three dots), and the navigation drawer on the left.

To my app icon i used:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.color.Transparent);
```

But it happens that when the application starts it shows the icon and then it goes to transparent, and i would like to simply initialize my app without the icon.

I also would like to know how to center the text with my app/activity name.

[image: app bar]

Comment: You should read this post: http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous by Cyril Mottier. It explains that customize style, especially the ActionBar, starts your app more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use a style for your action bar.

Within your styles.xml file under your values folder you can edit it such that you AppTheme uses a specific style for your action bar. Within that specific style you can declare your icon attribute. This let's the action bar know from the get go that you have a specific icon for it and will show it to begin with eliminating the temporary pause.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>   


<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

As you can see in the style "AppTheme" I add:

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
```

This states that I want my app to take into account a custom style for the action bar called "MyActionBarStyle"

You can also see I that I declare that style with:

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

In this declaration I can set the icon to be a drawable or color (as we did in this instance). Hope this helps.

Also this example assumes you're using the support library. If not then just make sure you replace 'AppCompat' with 'Holo', 'icon' with 'android:icon', and 'actionBarStyle' with 'android:actionBarStyle'. I learned that the hard way :)

Comment: It worked for me by replacing what you have told me to replace, plus replacing "@style/" by "android:", and changing in manifest the application theme by "@style/MyActionBarStyle". Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it programatically as follows:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

Hope it Helps!

Regards!

Comment: this solution is similar to mine and does not work. it has the same effect: when the app starts it shows the icon and then goes to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, actionbar supports,

```
setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```